# seing a position for the placeholder

Tags: html, css

I am using a placeholder attribute for my textfield which is being used as a search field. However i am trying to position my placeholder which currently is not exactly in the middle (vertically). Hence i was wondering if anyone could help me with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `line-height` as height on the `textfield`

For example write like this:

```
input{
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
}
```